# skip some subdirectories on lftp

Tags: lftp

i'm using lftp to download data.

my command looks like

`lftp -u $ftpuser,$ftppass -p 21 $ftpserver -e "set ftp:ssl-allow on; set ssl:check-hostname no; mirror -P $ftpconnections $ftproot $backupfolder/$date-$user/ --exclude images/product_images/popup_images/ --exclude images/product_images/info_images/ --exclude images/product_images/thumbnail_images/   --exclude-glob '*.log*'  --exclude-glob '*.zip*'; quit"`

excluding those sub-directories doesn't work, the system's still downloading them and i don't know why...

`--exclude images/`  works fine, but that's not what i want...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for everyone with the same problem.

the command should be

```
lftp -u $ftpuser,$ftppass -p 21 $ftpserver -e "set ftp:ssl-allow on; set ssl:check-hostname no; mirror -P $ftpconnections $ftproot $backupfolder/$date-$user/ --exclude popup_images/ --exclude info_images/ --exclude thumbnail_images/   --exclude-glob '*.log*'  --exclude-glob '*.zip*'; quit"
```

So my problem was that i tried to exclude a server path instead of just the name of the folder.